# LWP / IO::Socket::SSL fails with SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO:wrong cipher returned

Tags: windows, perl, ssl, lwp

I found many questions quite similiar to my problem, but they didn't solve it, so here I am asking for your help.

I am trying to get data from web page with Perl LWP using https.
I can get data from almost every site I have tried, except the one I really need to use.
I am using Perl version v5.18.2 under Windows x64.
This is my basic dummy example:

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'https://www.domainx.com:443';
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $url);
my $response = $ua->request($req);
print $response->status_line . "\n";
```

And result for the response->status_line:
`500 Can't connect to www.domainx.com:443`

Debug for SSL:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1890: new ctx 48125200
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:393: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:395: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:413: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:443: using SNI with hostname www.domainx.com
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:466: set socket to non-blocking to enforce     timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:479: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:489: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:499: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:519: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:479: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1359: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:485: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:14092105:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_HELLO:wrong cipher returned
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1924: free ctx 48125200 open=48125200
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1932: OK free ctx 48125200
```

From checking the previous posts I tried to apply: ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 }, but that didn’t help.
If I try to connect to that same site with browser (IE or Chrome) it works just fine.

Is this some certificate based error or what is going wrong here?

Comment: This is a handshake error and can not be fixed by disabling certificate validation. I would be helpful if you provide the real target hostname and also the version of IO::Socket::SSL and the underlying openssl you are using.

Comment: The actual site is www.firstcard.fi
And package IO::Socket::SSL; - our $VERSION = '1.962';
I'll have to check that openssl -version later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The actual site is www.firstcard.fi

The server is heavily broken as can also be seen from the [report by SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=firstcard.fi&s=62.13.0.65&latest). To get a connection to the server one must work around these problems by only using the single good cipher the server offers:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->ssl_opts(SSL_cipher_list => 'DES-CBC3-SHA');
```

Interestingly, this cipher is included in the cipher list used by default in IO::Socket::SSL but the server is too broken to properly deal with the correct ClientHello.

Comment: Hi. This seems to work. Thank you very much !!
How did you find out that right cipher?

Comment: This can be seen from the SSLLabs report I have linked to. But at the end I have various tools to test sites (openssl s_client, https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl) and I have experiences with other broken sites.

Comment: Thank you one more time.